# Active profile ignored

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

[Sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcFRs.png)

I have already added "spring.profiles.active=local" in application.properties file
But while running the application it is not able to recognize the profile and running with default profile

**application.properties**

```
# Tomcat Server Config
server.port=8071

#Profile Config
spring.profiles.active=local
```

**application-local.properties**

```
# Spring JPA Config
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/User
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=amt123`

# Hibernate Config
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Comment: Where's your `application.properties` file located?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please to not post your code as off-site image. Please paste your code and (error) messages right into your question. You can use the formatting to format your code properly.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further information on how to ask questions. 
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for further information on formatting.

Comment: When I running the jar file using "java -jar" command it is running using the specified profile but when I am running using IDE its not able to detect the profile and falling back to default profile

Comment: @cassiomolin It located at src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

"spring.devtools.add-properties" default value is true
Once it is set to false, spring boot disables profile configuration.
For me even if I set the value to true, still profile configuration was not enabled

I fixed this issue by removing the dev-tool dependency and adding it again.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure on the internal workflow.
If anyone has a proper explanation for this, please comment